# Mongodb difference to previous entry

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a mongodb collection that contain the following:

```
[{'price': 0.74881,,
  'date': '20160601 00:00:00.134',
  'instrument': 'EUR/GBP'},
 {'price': 0.76881,
  'date': '20160601 00:00:00.135',
  'instrument': 'EUR/GBP'},
 {'price': 0.78881,
  'date': '20160601 00:00:00.300',
  'instrument': 'EUR/GBP'},
 {'price': 1.76881,
  'date': '20160601 00:00:00.302',
  'instrument': 'EUR/GBP'},
```

How can I update each record so it contains the percentage increase/decrease of the bid and ask to the previous record? The real record contains millions of entries so pandas is not suitable.

In the output each record should contain contain an additional field in each record called price_change_to_pervious_item

Comment: Your question is hard to understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: These are stock prices. For each record I would like to calculate how much it increased or decreased in comparison to the previous transaction.

Comment: You "date" field value will not be easy to work with. Also please consider to include the expected output in your question.

Comment: You are welcome to alter the date field to something more convenient (an integer?) if that helps

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to process your records in a pairwise fashion.
This function is from the [itertools documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) itself.

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
  "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
  a, b = tee(iterable)
  next(b, None)

  return izip(a, b)
```

Once you have that, and assuming your data is sorted

```
results = []
for d1, d2 in pairwise(data):
  if not result:
    d1['price_change_to_pervious_item'] = 0.0
    results.append(d1)
  delta = d2['price'] - d1['price']
  d2['price_change_to_pervious_item'] = delta
  results.append(d2)
```

This is not tested, but you get the general idea. Pairwise allows you to process rows in a (d1,d2), (d2,d3) manner.

Comment: Once you have the pairs, they are independent, so you could use multiprocessing on the processing of your data, minus the `if not result` hack to shoehorn the initial delta.

Comment: Thanks for that. In terms of speed, is there anything better than mongodb that I could use if the amount of data exceeds my RAM?

Comment: If you want pure speed without much work, I would use a SQL database, such as Postgresql and write a window function using the lag function, which is going to be just like the pairwise approach except that you can do everything in one statement. If you have millions or billions of rows, I would consider using Redshift on amazon or downloading and setting up Vertica. Both have column level compression and support multiple nodes. In my experience a set operation in sql is your best bet. Good luck.